# Is there a name for rings of the form $R/\mathfrak{q}$ with $\mathfrak{q}$ primary?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In a unital commutative ring $R$, a lot of the times we characterize the property of an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ by the property of the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak{a}$. Examples are if $\mathfrak{a}$ is prime, maximal, radical then $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is respectively integral domain, field, reduced. In all of these examples we do the following

> The ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subset R$ has property P if and only if the zero ideal of $R/\mathfrak{a}$ has property P.

Out of curiosity I asked myself if $\mathfrak{q}$ is primary, then what property does $R/\mathfrak{q}$ have? The answer is:

> An ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset R$ is primary if and only if every zero-divisor of $R/\mathfrak{q}$ is nilpotent. As a result the nilradical of $R/\mathfrak{q}$ is prime under either condition; it is the unique minimal prime ideal of $R/\mathfrak{q}$.

I am wondering whether there are names for these rings:

- A ring $R$ in which all zero-divisors are nilpotent.
- A ring $R$ which has a unique minimal prime ideal.

These rings seem to be rather important, so I would be surprised if there is not a name for them. However googling didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the first one called (unsurprisingly) a *primary ring*. ([Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1958-089-01/S0002-9947-1958-0098763-0/S0002-9947-1958-0098763-0.pdf) is an interesting paper I remember reading about types of primary rings and ideals in noncommutative rings, for example.)

I say "unsurprising" because in general ring theory you say that $R/P$ is a *prime ring* if $P$ is prime, and $R/S$ is a semiprime ring if $S$ is a semiprime ideal. These boil down to domains and reduced rings for commutative rings, of course.

I have thought a bit and searched the literature about rings of the second type, but I have never seen a name for them. ([Here](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ40_02%2FS0017089500032547a.pdf&code=d4262db4d871c55400062d1042e9273c) is an interesting paper I had found on unique minimal prime ideals.)